# Duvida com regra de negócio entre classe aluno e turma

Tags: java

Estou com uma dúvida em um código, sou novo em programação, se alguém puder me ajudar, serei grato.

- A classe aluno receberá o nome do aluno;
- A classe turma receberá uma coleção de alunos e o nome da turma

Todo o processo está sendo feito no código, a única falha está em adicionar uma nova turma, quando crio uma nova turma e insiro um aluno que já está matriculado em outra turma, o programa não aceita, ele avisa que o aluno já está matriculado e não altera a sua turma, porém quando listo a segunda turma criada, o aluno está lá, porém apontado pra primeira turma que ele foi alocado.

Alguém pode me ajudar em uma regra que quando o aluno já está vinculado a uma turma, ele não adiciona na nova coleção.

Está bem claro que o problema é na classe turma, ali no construtor, mas não sei como colocar já ali pra bloquear o aluno se já estiver vinculado a uma turma.

Abaixo o codigo:

Classe Aluno

```
import java.util.Collection;

public class Aluno {

    private String nome;
    private Turma turma;

    public Aluno(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void addTurma(Turma turma) {
        if (this.turma == null) {
            this.setTurma(turma);
        } else {

            System.out.println("Aluno " + getNome() + ", Já está matricula em uma turma");
        }
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Turma getTurma() {
        return turma;
    }

    public void setTurma(Turma turma) {
        this.turma = turma;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Aluno: " + nome + ", " + getTurma();
    }
}
```

Classe Turma:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Turma {

    private String nome;
    private Collection<Aluno> alunos;

    public Turma(String nome, Collection<Aluno> alunos) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.alunos = new ArrayList<>();
        /* Verifica se o Aluno já está no array Alunos, caso não ele adiciona 
         e tambem adiciona o nome do aluno na classe turma*/
        for (Aluno a : alunos) {
            if (!this.alunos.contains(a)) {
                this.alunos.add(a);
                a.addTurma(this);
            } else {
                System.out.println("o " + a + ", já está matriculado em uma turma");
            }
        }
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Collection<Aluno> getAlunos() {
        return alunos;
    }

    public void setAlunos(Collection<Aluno> alunos) {
        this.alunos = alunos;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Turma: " + nome;
    }

}
```

Classe que testa a turma:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class TestaTurma {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Aluno aluno1 = new Aluno("Jose Almeida");
        Aluno aluno2 = new Aluno("Lucas Henrique");
        Aluno aluno3 = new Aluno("Carlos Soares");

        List lista1 = new ArrayList();
        lista1.add(aluno1);
        lista1.add(aluno2);

        Turma turma1 = new Turma("4ºA", lista1);

        List lista2 = new ArrayList();
        lista2.add(aluno1);
        lista2.add(aluno3);
        Turma turma2 = new Turma("6ºA", lista2);

        System.out.println("Alunos 4ºA");
        System.out.println(turma1.getAlunos());
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Alunos 6ºA");
        System.out.println(turma2.getAlunos());

    }

}
```

Comment: Qual a relação entre aluno e turma?

Answer (score 1):

user45813 seu erro encontra-se exatamente no construtor da classe Turma.

Na linha  17 e 22 da classe TestaTurma você cria dois Objetos, turma1 e turma2, respectivamente. Porém, na linha 15 da classe Turma, você testa se o atributo alunos, do tipo Collection, já contém algum aluno da lista que você enviou para o método construtor, mas como você acabou de instanciar esse objeto, esse Collection estará vazio e a condição será sempre verdadeira. Se na linha 15 da classe turma você fizer o seguinte:

```
if (a.getTurma() == null)
```

O Programa funcionará exatamente como o desejado.
Bom estudos.